# Ok to use Google Code to host javascript apps for end users?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am working on a javascript app that users load via a configurable script tag. I have it hosted on its own Google Code project since its open source. Is it ok to have the url that loads the app pointed at the file download link on its Code site? For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myprojectname.googlecode.com/files/myproject.js"></script>
```

I know that the common JS libs like jQuery and prototype are hosted similarly, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/tos.html

> You agree that Google has no responsibility or liability for the deletion or failure to store any Content and other communications maintained or transmitted by Google services. You acknowledge that Google may have set no fixed upper limit on the number of transmissions you may send or receive through Google services or the amount of storage space used; however, we retain the right, at our sole discretion, to create limits at any time with or without notice.

Comment: So basically it sounds like its ok to do, until its not.

Comment: Its ok when a couple people do it but when the script is popular and there are tons of people hotlinking to it, it might get pulled. I'd encourage you and your clients to host the scripts themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody makes a change to the app in Google Code, then it will affect visitors to your page that uses it.  This may or may not be what you want.  You may rather have a chance to review changes before implementing them.